# How to introduce adiabatic heat flux in abaqus

Tags: flux, surface, abaqus, heat

I would like to introduce two types of heat flux in this example (the photo in the attachment):

The first type is a surface heat flux applied to the red surface. In Abaqus, there is a function called 'surface heat flux' which allows me to introduce this type of flux.
The second type is an adiabatic heat flux applied to the remaining surfaces.
My question is how to introduce the second type, 'adiabatic heat flux', in Abaqus. I have not found a dedicated function for that in Abaqus.

[image]